# how to access global constants inside a JSON file

Tags: json, vue.js

I have many JSON files in a Vue.js application, with numerous references to global constants. Is it possible to import constants into a json file, or to refer to .env constants from my .json files?

The following examples break my tests:

```
"href": process.env.SOME_EXTERNAL_LINK, or
"href": "$(process.env.SOME_EXTERNAL_LINK)", or
"href": `${process.env.SOME_EXTERNAL_LINK}`
```

Is there a "standard" way to do this?

Comment: No. Just convert them to JS. It's as simple as adding `export default` to the beginning.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible to reference or import constants from within a `JSON` file. Converting these JSON files into `JavaScript` files seem to be the only solution. In this way, the desired constants can be imported.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion of Estus Flask is correct - this is the best way forward.